# Python pandas automate copying cell til next blank, using Excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to work through a number of data formatting challenges on an Excel spreadsheet that I've extracted from IBM Bluemix.

Using Python, so far I've worked out how to use the SoftLayer API to connect to our instance and pull down the latest invoice in .xls format. Then using pandas and xlsxwriter I've started formatting a new spreadsheet. So far so good.

The latest headscratcher is that I have a new column in which I need to copy the first cell all the way down until it reaches a blank cell (as that will be where the next item begins).

To start with, that column looks like this:

```
SERVERNAME1
Public Network Port: 0 Mbps Public Uplink*
First Hard Drive: 1.00 TB SATA 
Uplink Port Speeds: 1 Gbps Private Network Uplink
Primary IPv6 Addresses: 1 IPv6 Address
Operating System: Vyatta 6.x Subscription Edition (64 bit)
Primary IP Addresses: 1 IP Address
Disk Controller: SATA Disk Controller
RAM: 8 GB DDR3 1333
Second Hard Drive: 1.00 TB SATA 
Public Bandwidth: 0 GB Bandwidth
Sub-Total:

SERVERNAME2
Server: Single Intel Xeon E3-1270 v3 (4 Cores, 3.50 GHz)
Operating System: Vyatta 6.x Subscription Edition (64 bit)
RAM: 8 GB DDR3 1333
Second Hard Drive: 1.00 TB SATA 
Uplink Port Speeds: 1 Gbps Public & Private Network Uplinks
Public Bandwidth: 20000 GB Bandwidth
Disk Controller: RAID
First Hard Drive: 1.00 TB SATA 
Public Network Port: 1 Gbps Public Uplink*
Primary IP Addresses: 1 IP Address
Primary IPv6 Addresses: 1 IPv6 Address
Sub-Total:

SERVERNAME3
Server: Single Intel Xeon E3-1270 v3 (4 Cores, 3.50 GHz)
RAM: 8 GB DDR3 1333
First Hard Drive: 1.00 TB SATA 
Public Bandwidth: 20000 GB Bandwidth
etc.
```

It needs to end up looking like this:

```
SERVERNAME1
SERVERNAME1
SERVERNAME1
SERVERNAME1
SERVERNAME1
SERVERNAME1
SERVERNAME1
SERVERNAME1
SERVERNAME1
SERVERNAME1
SERVERNAME1
SERVERNAME1

SERVERNAME2
SERVERNAME2
SERVERNAME2
etc.
```

I've got as far as

```
data_xls = pd.read_excel('Excel_Latest_Invoice.xls', 'Detailed Billing', header = [1], index_col = None, parse_cols = "A,B:D,F:L")

data_xls.insert(0, 'Server', '')

        <.... Lots of code excluded for brevity .....>

data_of_interest = (f for f in data_xls['Server'])
for f in data_of_interest:
      print(f)               #Just to validate the correct data range
```

But whilst I can see the data I want to change with my print function, I can't work out how to choose the topmost cell in that range and copy it down...

I appreciate this is probably super simple, but I'm coming at this as a complete newbie, and I've managed to get a reasonable way with it all, so I don't want to fail here! Any assistance will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing exactly what your blank lines are once your Excel doc is imported into pandas, my example assumes they are NaN, but you can change whatever they actually are in the second part of the first line below and you should get the output you're looking for.

*Update - based on OP commnt, this has been updated to handle the blank lines as NaN and using `0` as a placeholder for the column header.*

```
data_xls[0].replace(np.nan, '', inplace = True)
data_xls.loc[(data_xls[0].str[:10] != 'SERVERNAME') & (data_xls[0] != '')] = None
data_xls.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thanks for this @pshep123 - it's still not quite working, as the blank cells are NaN. I've tried substituting your `(data_xls[0] != " ")` for `(data_xls[0] != data_xls[0])` but I'm getting a type error...

Comment: Changed it back to your suggestion and it's still the same error, which is interesting:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sl_extract.py", line 86, in <module>
    data_xls.loc[(data_xls[0].str[-4:] != '.com') & (data_xls[0] != " ")] = None`
Followed by a number of pandas references, and finally:
`KeyError: 0`

Comment: Ok, that error is due to the fact that I assumed that `pd.read_excel` made the first column header name `0`, which I'm guessing isn't the case.  Is the column header name `Server`?  Basically, replace the `0` with whatever the column header name is.  That said I'm updating the answer to deal with the `NaN` issue as well.

Comment: Yes! That's got it, fantastic, thank you! I was getting confused because, even with your corrections, it was iterating across the whole workbook. So I stepped through my code, adding comments, and came across two errors that were preventing it from executing as intended. 

The whole thing works now, and looks like this:

[pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/5zvgs5WL)

Comment: Phil, I just looked at your pastebin link and the code in question is inside a loop.  No need for it to be - take it out of the `for` loop and you'll get the same result - and faster!